# HTTPS monitoring on Android

Tags: android, https, charles-proxy

I'm trying to monitor HTTPS calls from a third party app developer on Android using Charles and I'm not having any luck.  I'm on OS X.11.  I used Charles and created a Root Certificate and mailed it to the phone.  I think I installed it, but when I launch the app it appears that the HTTPS calls fail.

I'm happy to try any other means to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to enable the proxy in your device. Just follow this tutorial and it should work: http://jaanus.com/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with-charles-proxy-for-fun-and-profit/

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the computer and the phone and it now works.